# Disk space, I delete files and the available status shown is not altered

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, disk-space

Equipment: MacBook Pro
MacOS: Monterrey

Dear colleagues, I would like to ask if any of you have experience of having dealt with this or similar problem and what alternative or possible solution you recommend.
It has been happening to me for a while, but the most noticeable change happened to me a few days ago when when deleting more than 50GB Approx. Note that the “Disk Utilities” indicator bar had no impact on it.

However, if I proceed to look at “About this MAC” > “Storage” there I can see the total available disk space.

And I tried restarting the SMC and PRAM, NVRAM and I had no changes when carrying out these processes.
Can anyone tell me what solution I can have in this regard without updating my MacOS?

Comment: Did you empty the trash as well, use `rm`, or delete them without emptying the trash?

Comment: I found the solution! The problem was TimeMachine!
running the command in terminal:

tmutil listlocalsnapshots /

sudo tmutil deletelocalsnapshots "2023-12-11-123740"

I was able to solve the problem of the displayed space!